# Block GSM communication of a cellular modem with AT commands

Tags: security, gsm

I have a cellular modem that supports GSM, 3G and LTE.
I want for security reasons to block/disable GSM support, meaning that it will not be able to connect to any GSM BTS.

Partial solutions I came up with so far:

1. There is an AT^SYSCONFIG command, which allows to determine the system mode to be one of the following: GSM only, WCDMA only, TD-SCDMA only, LTE only or automatic. However, there is no possibility for multiple selection (as I want to disable only GSM and support all others).
   Additionally it has another parameter that determines access order e.g UTRAN first, GSM second. However it will not block completely GSM, and in the absence of UTRAN BTS it will connect to GSM ones.
2. There is the AT$QCBANDPREF command which sets the frequency bands preference. In the possible bands there are both GSM and Non-GSM bands (e.g. Band 24 is GSM_850 and Band 27 is WCDMA_I_IMT_2000). However there are general bands that can populate both GSM and non-GSM communication (e.g. BC1,2,3..). So if I block all general bands then I possibly block non-GSM communication as well.
3. The is the AT+WS46 command, which selects the cellular network wireless data service to operate with the TA. Here there is an option to select only UTRAN and E-UTRAN networks (meaning that GERAN network will not be supported), however this only covers data communication as far as I understand, and will not block the GSM connection itself, or the ability to receive calls and SMS messages from a GSM BTS.

So, is there a way to completely block the GSM technology without changing the hardware modem chip to some chip that does not support GSM?

Comment: What's the security issue you are concerned about ? Will you be doing clear text communication on the channel ? Wont you use some form of secure socket on top ?

Comment: The first thing would probably be to tell us what module you are talking about. Also remember that in many places GSM networks have already been shut down and in many more this will happen soon.